# Display error message on gridview row based on textBox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dictionary, textbox

I am trying to do like if checkbox is marked on certain rows in gridview, I will check if the user inputs exceed storage level. If exceed, I will display an error message using a label binded just next to the textbox. Here is how I set up my gridview binded in a repeater:

```
<!-- Collapsible panel extender body -->
<asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
    <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
    <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
    <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="998px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckRow" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                               
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="650px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="inventoryQuantity" HeaderText="Total Unit" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Width="60" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "unitQuantity") %>'/>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCheckAmount" runat="server" Visible="true" ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is the code when button is on click:

```
string quantity = "", prodID = "";
int packagesNeeded = 0, totalUnit = 0;
Dictionary<string, string> tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//Get the total packages needed for this distribution
packagesNeeded = prodPackBLL.getPackagesNeededByDistributionID(distributionID);

foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
        GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                //Get the productID which set as DataKeyNames and unit quantity from selected row index
                prodID = gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                var tbQuantity = gr.FindControl("tbQuantity") as TextBox;
                if (tbQuantity != null)
                {
                    quantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                }

                //Add both objects into Dictionary
                tempList.Add(prodID, quantity);
            }
        }
    }
}
//Loop thru tempList. key as prodID, tempList.Keys as quantity
foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
{
    //Get total unit of each products
    totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
    //Here check if exceed storage
    if (((Convert.ToInt32(quantity)) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
            GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
            {
                Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient amount";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the checkbox and other things work perfectly. Just that when one record is insufficient, all the row will display the error message even though they are sufficient. What I am trying to do is display error message on the row that are insufficient only.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the `key` value matches the `DataKey` value of each row when looping through the gridview. Here's the portion that needs to be changed:

```
    //Loop thru tempList. key as prodID, tempList.Keys as quantity
    foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
    {
        //Get total unit of each products
        totalUnit = prodPackBLL.getTotalProductUnit(key);
        //Here check if exceed storage
        if (((Convert.ToInt32(tempList[key])) * packagesNeeded) > totalUnit)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
            {
                Panel pnl = item.FindControl("pBody1") as Panel;
                GridView gv = pnl.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                foreach (GridViewRow gr in gv.Rows)
                {
                    // compare the key with the data key of the current row
                    if (key == gv.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        // display the insufficient message
                        Label lblCheckAmount = gr.FindControl("lblCheckAmount") as Label;
                        lblCheckAmount.Text = "Insufficient amount";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now the error message narrowed down to be displayed at the checked row. And the checking is just for the last items in the list. Let's say I got prod 1,2,6,7. It only checks the last items.

Comment: Just edited my answer, I figured you still use the quantity variable instead of tempList[key]

Comment: Oh ya sorry my bad. Sorry for troubling you again on the same questions. It works now thanks a lot